# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Fails on Partially Offline Deployment Group

Tags: azure-devops

I'm currently using Azure DevOps for CI/CD and have set up a deployment group with multiple target machines. Some of these machines are scheduled to go offline during the night . However, I've noticed that when even one of these machines is offline, my release pipeline fails to deploy to the entire group, including the online machines. The error message I receive is: "Deployment Group deployment configuration settings are not met."

My goal is to have the release pipeline deploy successfully to the online machines, even if some machines in the deployment group are offline.

Is there a configuration setting or workaround in Azure DevOps to handle this scenario?
How can I ensure that the pipeline continues to deploy to online machines without being halted by offline ones?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply tags to the targets (e.g. Active) and use that as a filter in the stage tasks.

Comment: Yeah, ended up doing exactly that, adding Online tags to the currently online machines before every deployment